# What's the difference between Average Square Error and Mean Square Error? Are they the same thing?

Tags: sas, mse

I have a bit of confusion regarding ASE and MSE as in SAS Enterprise Miner it shows these two measurement scales. What is the difference or similarity between the two and why are they both so similar?

Example screenshot is shown below.

[image]

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Mining-and-Machine/Mean-Squared-Error-vs-Average-Squared-Error/td-p/284742

Comment: What kind of model? Could it be an issue of $n$ vs $n-p$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Dave That's what Sycorax's reference says.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Data-Mining-and-Machine/Mean-Squared-Error-vs-Average-Squared-Error/td-p/284742) on the SAS forums, the different values reflect the difference between dividing by the number of observations $n$ and dividing by the degrees of freedom $n - p$.

- Average square error is computed as $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2}{n}$$
- Mean square error is computed as $$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2}{n-p}$$